# How to quickly add many columns to GWT DataGrid

Tags: gwt, datagrid

I am currently trying to create a DataGrid that can take an entity with a list of values as a row. Each value in the list is in its own column in the DataGrid. The entities' lists of values may have different sizes, so the DataGrid will have a variable number of columns. I have noticed that when I try to create the DataGrid and loop over the process of adding each of the column to the DataGrid, the time it takes to add the columns does not grow linearly.

Here is the code I was using to test the quickness of adding the columns

```
DataGrid<String> table = new DataGrid<String>();
table.setPageSize(25);
int NUM_COLUMNS = 40;

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_COLUMNS; i++) {
    GWT.log("Adding column "+i);
    TextColumn<String> nameColumn = new TextColumn<String>() {
        public String getValue(String object) {
        return object;
        }
    };

    table.addColumn(nameColumn, "Column " + i);
    table.setColumnWidth(nameColumn, 100, Unit.PX);
}

ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    data.add("row "+i);
}

table.setRowCount(data.size(), true);
table.setRowData(0, data);
table.setWidth("100");
```

This took about 48 seconds, give or take 1 second, every time I ran it. It seems that loading less than 10 columns were fairly quickly, but as the number of columns grew, the time it took to load it grew exponentially.

Is there another way to add columns to the DataGrid that would be quicker? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One question you might want to ask yourself is if there's a better way to do it. A table with 40 columns (IMO) seems inefficient. In general, you're going to have significant performance loss when loading more than ~15 columns in a `DataGrid`, and `FlexTable` isn't any better.

I've worked with `DataGrid` quite a bit and haven't seen any of the behavior you're talking about, though in my case they typically only have 10 or fewer columns with several thousand rows. (Data is of course paged and not being jammed in all at once.)

One thing I've noticed does speed it up is pre-rendering. Are you adding the table to the DOM prior to adding all these columns, or are you adding them all first? Lots of time can be spent waiting for the DOM to update. If you're adding it to the page after rendering everything, you're probably looking at the best speed you'll get, since there's no built-in function for adding multiple columns simultaneously.

Comment: That is what I feared. The columns are necessary and most of the times will have less than 15, but a few have dozens. I set the row data for the DataGrid last, just like above so I guess I will have to try to find a creative way to deal with the columns. Thank you anyways. Hopefully someone else may have an idea.